# How make mariadb federated with ssh

Tags: mysql, mariadb

How make mariadb federated with ssh?

```
DROP SERVER IF EXISTS `any_server_name`;

CREATE SERVER ' any_server_name ' FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER 'mysql' OPTIONS
(HOST 'host.com',
DATABASE 'database_name',
USER 'user_name',
PASSWORD "password",
PORT 3306,
SOCKET '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock',
OWNER 'root');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS federated_table_name;

CREATE TABLE federated_table_name (
column_1 INT(11) NOT NULL,
column_2 INT(11) NOT NULL,
column_3  VARCHAR(255),
...
column_n VARCHAR(256)
)
ENGINE="FEDERATED" DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
CONNECTION=' any_server_name /table_name';
```

Comment: it's not connected with ssh tunnel

Answer (score 0):

MariaDB doesn't support SSH, so you can only tunnel a connection and connect to the port of tunneled connection.

If you meant TLS/SSL instead of SSH, the answer is also **no**. CONNECT and FEDERATED engines don't support secure connections yet. A solution to store the TLS/SSL parameter in the `client.mariadb` section of the configuration file will also not work, since the call which forces to read the configuration file is commented out in the [source code](https://github.com/MariaDB/server/blob/10.4/storage/connect/myconn.cpp#L489).

If you need that feature, please file a task on [MariaDB Issue tracker](https://jira.mariadb.org)

A workaround for it would be to use table type ODBC and to pass the TLS/SSL parameters in the DSN.